# Не создается паттерн индекс elasticsearch + kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

пытаюсь создать паттерн индекс в кибане(6.8.7) management -> Index Patterns -> Create index pattern
указываю название, выбираю параметры создания, нажимаю Next step но ничего не происходит, просто крутится колесико, в консоли браузера ф12 - увидел ошибку `POST http://elastictest:5601/api/saved_objects/index-pattern 403 (Forbidden)`

начал гуглить данную ошибку, на одном сайте увидел комментарий, что решается проблема разблокировкой индексов, но как это делается информации не нашел.

Подскажите куда копать? может я что-то не так делаю?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказал в заблокированных индексах из-за нехватки места на диске и помогла команда

```
curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'
```